# Как закрыть вкладку с сайтом при нажатии на кнопку ОК

Tags: javascript

Есть диалоговое окно:

```
alert('q')
```

Как можно при нажатии на кнопку ОК закрыть вкладку с сайтом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, альтернативы есть? любые

Comment: Зависит от того, что это за вкладка и как открывается.... Если эта вкладка была открыта переходом по ссылке с target=_blank,  то можно через window.close ....... можно через расширение браузера - если этот вариант устраивает......ну и написать свой браузер вариант остаётся))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это через запуск файла. Локальный сайт

Comment: Тогда первый вариант точно отпадает и остаются второй и третий)

Comment: А зачем такое поведение нужно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне нужен ответ)))
У меня нет желания отвечать)))))

Comment: Ну тогда удачи получить нулевой ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `null` тоже ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Закрыть вкладку можно только если она была открыта по клику с другой вкладки.

И второй случай - если пользователь уже нажал на закрыть вкладку.

через запуск файла средствами яваскрипт - никак.

### Но если у вас локальный сайт и запускается какой-то файл, то ...

Запускайте вкладку с новым профилем в подпроцессе. `--user-data-dir="ПУТЬ_ПО_ПАПКИ"` параметр. После алерта делайте запрос на локальный сайт, который прочитает айди подпроцесса и убьет его.

Comment: Это хорошо что можно, а как?

Comment: @ΝNL993 window.close() как же ещё?

Comment: Так это надо в ответе писать :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 но ответ - никак

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitriy Parkhomenko, если вам нужно закрыть именно ту вкладку, в которой запускается скрипт, то после alert пропишите window.close():

```
// Для закрытия вкладки после вывода нужного сообщения

alert("q");
window.close();

// Для вывода по действию пользователя

a = confirm("Закрыть вкладку?");

if (a == true)
{
  window.close();
}

else
{
  alert("Не закрываю");
}
```

Comment: Увы даже с проверкой нельзя

Comment: Этот вариант сработает только в одном конкретном случае.....а...не....в двух

Comment: Да, нельзя, ведь это метод alert - он всегда возвращает true. Если вам нужно именно подтверждение пользователя, то вызовите лучше метод confirm.

Пример:


`a = confirm("Закрыть вкладку?");

if (a == true)
{
  window.close();
}

else
{
  alert("Не закрываю");
}`

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, так тоже не будет работать))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, перепроверьте, пожалуйста, у меня всё работает. Если вам конкретно нужно чтобы вкладка закрывалась вместе с браузером, то, конечно, данный метод вам не подходит.

Comment: у вас работает только из-за того, что вы на страницу пришли по ссылке.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как ещё можно перейти на страницу? 

Comment: А почему вы решили. что на неё перешли, а не, например, просто вбили адрес в браузере? Или например просто открыли с диска на ПК? Или открыли в фрейме? Или переадресовали? Или перезагрузили (сделали replace) href и push state? да вариантов масса.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, все способы, описанные вами, не мешают выполнению скрипта (по поводу фрейма, replace, href, push state - не знаю, не буду ничего утверждать). Если что, скрипт создавался в Visual Studio Code, вместе с .html файлом. Вероятно, мы друг друга не понимаем.

Comment: Вполне себе мешают. вот  возьмите адрес  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463678/   вбейте во вкладке.....далее в консоли  исполните свой код... и посмотрите. что он не работает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, теперь я вас понял. Действительно, данный метод может закрывать только открытые им окна. Я теперь тоже буду знать, спасибо вам